# Update Table From Grid View Check Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table that lists all possible courses.  I am needing to create a grid view that will display all possible courses with a checkbox and if the checkbox is checked then insert the coursename, userid logged in, and datetime into a table.

I have no problem creating the gridview, what I can not figure out is how to have grid view based off one table, and update a secondary table based off checkbox?

Comment: you have plenty of tutorials online on binding GridView from Table and Firing an event on Checkbox click... Please start your code with that and come back here with any errors.

Comment: @techspider - can you point me to one?

Comment: you can go throw this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/277/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you transform your `course` object into a view model and bind that to your grid. Something like:

```
public class Course
{
   public int Userid {get; set;}
   public string CourseName {get; set;}
}

public class CourseViewModel
{
   public int Userid {get; set;}
   public string CourseName {get; set;}
   public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can transform your list of Courses into a list of CourseViewModels and bind that to the grid. On postback, you will have IsSelected property  to determine which inserts you need to do.